# solving $\int\int (x^{4}-y^{4})xydxdy$ over $G = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}: 0 \leq x,1 \leq x^{2}-y^{2} \leq2, 1\leq xy \leq 2\} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$\int\int (x^{4}-y^{4})xy$dxdy over $G = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}: 0 \leq x,1 \leq x^{2}-y^{2} \leq2, 1\leq xy \leq 2\} $

I thought about substitution by $u = x^{2}-y^{2}$ and $v = xy$. But i failed very hard. Thats why i'm asking for help/tips on how i should solve integrals like these...

Comment: Are you sure you failed? This is the correct approach.

Comment: i got the following things:

$x=\sqrt{u+y^{2}}$,
$y= \frac{v}{\sqrt{u+y^{2}}}$

Comment: Well, that's no good. You have to switch *everything* into $uv$ coordinates. What's the Jacobian of the change of variables? You don't need to solve for $x$ and $y$ to find this!

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = x^{2}-y^{2}$ and $v = xy$. Then $\frac{\partial(u, v)}{\partial(x, y)}=2(x^2+y^2)=2u$, so the Jacobian $J=\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(u, v)}=\frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)}$. Thus $\int\int (x^{4}-y^{4})xydxdy=\int_1^2\int_1^2(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)\frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)}xydudv=1/2\int_1^2\int_1^2uvdudv$. The result follows by direct integration.

Comment: $dxdy=J \cdot dudv$?